# How to stop php from opening a new tab in browser when submitting a from

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and I'm trying to have a form in which you have to input two numbers which are added to each other when submitted. 
It works just fine, but whenever I click submit it opens a new tab in my browser (tested in chrome and firefox) to show to anwser, which I don't want.
I write the php code in the same file as my html.
Can anyone help me? 
Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<form target="/index.php" method="GET">
    <input type="number" name="num1">
    <input type="number" name="num2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>anwser:</p> 
<?php
     echo $_GET["num1"] + $_GET["num2"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php has nothing to do with new window or not...

its your target what does it... it opens a new window with internal name "/index.php"
what you are looking for is action="/index.php"

```
<form action="/index.php" method="GET">
    <input type="number" name="num1">
    <input type="number" name="num2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>anwser:</p> 
<?php
    echo $_GET["num1"] + $_GET["num2"];
?>
```